# Use tt_address fields in direct_mail newsletter

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using `TYPO3 6.2.11`, `tt_address 2.3.5` and `direct_mail 4.0.1` and sent me some test newsletters from a internal TYPO3-Page. Everything works fine.

Now, I want to send some data fields from my `tt_address`-table like `name` or `title` for example.

What's the name of the tt_address-MARKER, I'll use at my page content?

I also add the follwing to `[basic.addRecipFields]` at the direct_mail-Extension:

```
name,first_name,last_name,email,description,title
```

But nothing happens. I can't use tt_address-fields at my direct_mail newsletter. I hope someone can help me, thanks.

---

The other opportunity is to use `fe_user`-data for my newsletter (felogin). How can I use felogin-fields like `password`or `username` at my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix the fields with `USER_` and wrap the marker in `###`. So e.g. if you'd like to use the e-mail address, you write `###USER_email###`. You can find all possibilities in the [Direct Mail documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/direct_mail/UsersManual/PersonalizingDirectMailContent/Index.html).

A note on sending the password: This would be a huge security risk but it's not possible anyway because passwords of fe_users are stored at least hashed (and nowadays also encrypted) in the database. But you can use the `###SYS_AUTHCODE###` marker to generate an authentication code you can use in an "edit profile" extension to let the user update his subscription.

If you need fields from other sources or data you're calculating dynamically, you can also create an own extension and implement the Direct Mail mailMarkersHook.

**ext_localconf.php:**

```
// Direct Mail personalization hook
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/direct_mail']['res/scripts/class.dmailer.php']['mailMarkersHook']['userunilunewsletterrendering'] =
    'My\Extension\Hook\DirectMail->mailMarkersHook';
```

**EXT:extension/Classes/Hook/DirectMail.php:**

```
<?php
namespace My\Extension\Hook;

class DirectMail {

    public function mailMarkersHook($params, \DirectMailTeam\DirectMail\Dmailer $dmailer) {
        $params['markers']['###USER_SALUTATION###'] = $this->getPersonalizedSalutation($params['row']);
        return $params;
    }

    /**
     * @param $row
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPersonalizedSalutation($row) {
        $personalizedSalutation = 'Dear Sir or Madam';
        if (!empty($row['last_name']) && !empty($row['gender'])) {
            if ($row['gender'] === 'm') {
                $personalizedSalutation = 'Dear Mr. ' . $row['last_name'];
            } elseif ($row['gender'] === 'f') {
                $personalizedSalutation = 'Dear Ms. ' . $row['last_name'];
            }
        }
        return $personalizedSalutation;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi lorenz, thanks. It works, there are too many opportunities at the extension `direct_mail` and it's my first time I work with it. Now I use `###USER_email###` and `###USER_name###` from `tt_address`